# обновление страницы (div) при добавлении данных в бд

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, websocket

Здравствуйте . Перерыл весь интернет и ничего толком не нашел . Вообщем есть админка для интернет-магазина на yii-2 , где есть страница с заказами . Нужно сделать так , чтобы при добавлении нового заказа в бд div с заказами автоматически обновлялся . Читал об comet , long-polling , веб-сокеты , но на их примерах , как правило , только разные чаты делались . Что ж применять в моем случае? какие технологии использывать ? спасибо за ответы .

Comment: Вам нужно смотреть в сторону ZMQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

websocket - однозначно, для старых браузеров есть вариант реализации на флэш. простота реализации, минимальная нагрузка на сервер. только плюсы, минусов нет... говорю по приличной практике применения

Comment: пишите на php ?

Comment: нет,  на java. а в чем такой вопрос?

Comment: интересно  просто некоторые детали реализации именно на php

Comment: @KolyaVantukh , могу порекомендовать мои особенности реализации. как реализовать это на стороне сервера php - не могу сказать, но на стороне браузера, всё одинаково для любого сервера. работает великолепно и универсально.

Comment: буду очень благодарен

Comment: @KolyaVantukh рекуизиты для связи?

Comment: можете написать на емейл vkolia@mail.ua

Answer (score 3):

ajax, как ленивый вариант.

1. Пишем скрипт для сервера, проверяющий базу на наличие новых заказов. Можно просто брать данные из базы, где время добавления >= текущее время - 5 минут, и при наличии таких данных возвращать их в готовой разметке, если нет — возвращать false.
2. Пишем javascript, опрашивающий вышеупомянутый серверный скрипт раз в 5-15 секунд на наличие новых заказов и в случае наличия таковых — менять div.